# Outlook Table Relative Cell Reference Error

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-outlook, cells

I'm getting a "!(cell) Is Not In Table" error when attempting to create a Relative cell reference, inside of an outlook table, when using a formula.

I've tested the formula functions and they seem to work as long as I use an Absolute reference (with the format of R1C2, meaning Row 1, Column 2).

However, [Microsoft's support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-formula-in-a-word-or-outlook-table-cbd0596e-ea8a-485e-a35d-b2cb2c4f3e27#__toc281293384) on the topic states that you can simply use R to refer to the row of the formula, and C to refer to its column, to create a Relative reference (so RC1 should refer to the 1st column of the formula's row).

But, whenever I try that, the formula outputs the "!RC1 Is Not In Table" error:

[image: Example of working and non-working formulas]

Anyone know how to make a relative-referencing cell in Outlook?

(Note: Because of my department's security changes to Outlook, an embedded Excel spreadsheet will not work.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve through the relative cell reference (why aren't you using an absolute one)?

Comment: @Albin Purchase requests.  Most of our communication for our purchase approvals start with someone who isn't savvy with computers emailing someone who is. I'm trying to create an email template so that requests can be expanded upon easily, in case there happens to be a large number of items on a single request (which might happen with FY spending).

Comment: I see, so if I understand correctly, the main goal would be to enable them to use copy and paste on the formula, right? Or is the insertion of new lines "in-between" an issue as well?

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the table in Outlook email? Insert > Table?

Try click Insert > Table > Excel Spreadsheet. Then you can use the reference as the same in Excel.

[image]

Comment: Because of my department's security changes to Outlook, the embedded Excel spreadsheet solution has a lot of problems, including occasionally causing Outlook to force-close.  Yours was my first attempt at a solution, but it unfortunately won't work for what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hope someone else have any ideas. Outlook table is limited to basic functions. I'm not sure if this can be realized.

Answer (score 0):

I have a gut feeling the RnCn notation is an absolute address notation... although I couldn't find any official statement and I couldn't find any example for a relative address on the net for Word/Outlook tables. Who knows, maybe the support page is referencing s.th. that was never implemented, but I might be wrong there.

But if you want to use relative references in order to be able to add rows/columns (in your case I assume it's rows) without making changing all your formulas, you can use bookmarks as a work around:

- Select a cell you want to reference
- In the Ribbon goto "insert" and select "insert link" from the link-button dropdown menu
- Reference the cell by using the bookmark and not the cell address

If you add a row/column the bookmark will change accordingly, so your formulas will keep working.

(tested on Office 365)

Comment: While his answer doesn't solve my problem, Albin did go to lengths to attempt to find the solution I was looking for and so deserves the bounty.

Comment: @DanielZastoupil thanks, note, I left another comment on your question.